# Docker network layer resolving container name to wrong IP adress

Tags: docker, docker-networking

In a simplified example, I have 3 Docker containers located on 2 Docker networks:

```
Container_A : Connected to Network_1 and Network_2
Container_B : Connected to Network_1
Container_C : Connected to Network_2
```

When running `ping Container_B` from inside Container_A, the Docker network layer resolves the IP adress of Container_C instead of Contaier_B.

If I kill Container_C the name resolving will go back to the expected behaviour, but as soon as Container_C comes back online, the network layer starts resolving the wrong IP adresses again.

This has caused me a great headache and I have no idea how to fix this. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide your config. I have written a quick docker-compose file and docker is resolving everything properly:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx1:
    image: nginx:alpine
    networks:
      - network1
      - network2
  nginx2:
    image: nginx:alpine
    networks:
      - network1
  nginx3:
    image: nginx:alpine
    networks:
      - network2
networks:
  network1:
    external: true
  network2:
    external: true
```

Obviously, before running the docker-compose, you need to run:

`docker network create network1 && docker network create network2`

Comment: I am unable to create a minimal docker-compose that reproduces the same problem. This behaviour only occurrs with these specific containers.